# Is there an example of a complete JSON response for openweathermap?

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

The openweathermap [documentation](https://openweathermap.org/current#parameter) clearly and explicitly say

> If you do not see some of the parameters in your API response it means that these weather phenomena are just not happened for the time of measurement for the city or location chosen. Only really measured or calculated data is displayed in API response

That's well and fine but if I'm developing this now and want to be able to read about snow in a few months, how am I supposed to know all of the parameters? Is there an example of the a complete json object with all of the possible attributes so that I can develop against it now instead of brushing it up every time there's a new weather event?

Comment: I'm reading the docs as: _Hey, we're going to provide you all of these parameters you can evaluate, but there are times when a specific weather type may not have all of the parameters listed in the JSON sample._ I haven't used openweathermap, but the docs indicate there is a `weather.id` associated with a specific type of weather; and the `weather.main` is a more human readable version. Seems to me that you'd need to understand the `weather.id` values to determine when it's snowing.

Comment: What's wrong with the "fields in API response" section on the same page as  the paragraph you cited?

Answer (score 1):

Immediately below the paragraph you quoted, you saw the JSON sample that does not have all fields.

**Below that** there is a section with the title "Fields in API response" which looks like it contains all of the fields that are available.

Comment: <sigh> .... there are days and there are days. Thanks for pointing out what should have been obvious...